# If a function $x\mapsto xf(x)$ has a derivative at $a \ne0$, then $f$ is differentiable at $a$

Tags: real-analysis, proof-writing

> Prove if $x\mapsto xf(x)$ has a derivative at $a \neq 0$, then $f$ is differentiable at $a$.

The problem I'm encountering is with the setup.  If I am trying to show
$$\lim_{x \to a}\frac{f(x)-f(a)}{x-a},$$
would I first say that
$$\lim_{x \to a}\frac{xf(x)-xf(a)}{x(x-a)}?$$
I need this verified, and could use some guidance on finishing this proof.  Thanks!

Comment: Say what about that limit?

Comment: Let $g(x) = xf(x)$. You are wanting to show that if $g(x)$ has a derivative at $a$ then so does $g(x)/x$.

Comment: dfeuer, that is the limit definition of differentiability that we have been using in class.

Comment: I'm encouraging you to distinguish between an expression and a statement. What you wrote there makes about as much sense as "If I want to show $3$, should I first show $1\times 3$?" Neither of these is something that can be shown.

Comment: I'm using the limit definition to explain that xf(x) has a derivative at a, as given.  I'm not sure what you're trying to tell me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider $\frac{xf(x)-af(a)}{x-a}$. The limit of this as $x\to a$ exists.

Rewrite the top as $af(x)-af(a) +(x-a)f(x)$. Thus for $x\ne a$ we have 
$$\frac{xf(x)-af(a)}{x-a}=a\frac{f(x)-f(a)}{x-a}+f(x).$$
Now we are close to the end. Let $x\to a$. The left side has a limit. We will need to verify that $\lim_{x\to a}f(x)$ exists.

**Another way:** Let $g(x)=xf(x)$. Then $f(x)=\frac{1}{x}g(x)$. If you have already proved the Product Rule, the result follows immediately.

Comment: What would I need to do to verify that lim(x->a)f(x) exists?

Comment: Because it could be that $a\frac{f(x)-f(a)}{x-a}$ wiggles wildly near $x=a$, and $f(x)$ also wiggles wildly, in ways that cancel and allow $\frac{xf(x)-af(a)}{x-a}$ to be "nice."

Comment: I haven't proved the product rule, so I suppose that alternative is out.  I may be overthinking this, but I am still unsure how I would verify f(x) has a derivative at a.

Comment: The limit on the left exists. So the limit on the right exists. But the limit of $f(x)$ exists. Thus the limit of $a\frac{f(x)-f(a)}{x-a}$ exists. But $a\ne 0$. so the limit of $\frac{f(x)-f(a)}{x-a}$ exists.

Answer (score 1):

First of all $g$ has a derivative in $a$ if $\lim_{x \to a}\frac{g(x)-g(a)}{x-a}=g'(a)$ exists.

Now $g$ is differentiable at $a$ if $g'$ is continuous at $a$.

Now $\lim_{x \to a}\frac{xf(x)-af(a)}{x(x-a)}$ exists because $xf(x)$ has derivative in $a$. In this limit $\lim_{x \to a}\frac{xf(x)-af(a)}{x(x-a)}$ add and reduct $xf(a)$ or $af(x)$ and see what happens.